# How to make TableView2 recognize What i did select from TableView1?

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, core-data

iam new to swift and I'm trying to make an app where you can create Competition for Football/Soccer , here is a screenshot to understand what I'm working in [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoP7n.png)

the TableView1 which is where you choose an Competition you did Create [here screnchot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvqYP.png)

And TableView2 where you can put the result of the match

the problem is the TableView2 don't recognize what i did select from TableView1 ! and put all matches from all Competition i did create !!

so How to make TableView2 recognize What i did select from TableView1 ? and make it use only what i did select from TableView1

Maybe I'm using core data wrong

and sorry for my English is not good .

Comment: I guess you are asking about delegate method `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) `

Comment: In this method you will have to first identify the "TableView1" and then do operation on data array of "TableView2" and reload it.

Comment: I guess you are new to development and to SO. You are welcome. And while asking question put in some code so that people can help you easily.

Comment: sorry i can't put code idk why , i put func didSelectRowAtIndexPath and in the first screenshot my view recognize what i did select and then i moved to another view where tablevew2 is and  didn't recognize what i did select         i hope you understand me

Comment: Create a object in the TableView2's class. In didSelectRowAtIndexPath, set that object to the selected object. Now you can get what you selected in TableView1.